# DOS BATCH: How to compare the existence of 2 files with the same name in 2 separate folders?

Tags: file, batch-file, dos

I want to check all the files in one folder to see if they exist in another folder. When a file is found in the first folder that doesn't exist in the second folder I want that file to be deleted.

Is this possible?

Comment: Do you want to compare the files just by name, by name + size + timestamp or by md5sum/binary comparison perhaps?

Comment: Answer needs to be accepted by asker.

Answer (score 2):

Edit path info as appropriate (or incorprate batch arguments %1 %2), and remove ECHO that precedes DEL once you confirm you are getting the correct results.

```
@echo off
setlocal
set "dir1=."
set "dir2=d1"
set tempFile="%temp%\exclude%random%.txt"
dir /b "%dir2%" >%tempFile%
for /f "eol=: delims=" %%F in ('dir /b /a-d "%dir1%" ^| findstr /vixg:%tempFile%') do echo del "%dir1%\%%F"
del %tempFile%
```

***Note*** - This solution is simply comparing names. Two completely different files will be considered the same if they have the same name.

Comment: I tried this:setlocal
set "dir1="%USERPROFILE%\Documents"
set "dir2="S:\My Backup\My Documents 01\my documents"
set tempFile="%temp%\exclude%random%.txt"
dir /b "%dir2%" >%tempFile%
for /f "eol=: delims=" %%F in ('dir /b /a-d "%dir1%" ^| findstr /vixg:%tempFile%') do del "%dir2%\%%F"
del %tempFile%

Comment: @SteveOver - The code was attempting to delete from the wrong directory (%dir2%). All fixed now to correctly delete from %dir1%.